# how to replace special character from string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, replace

my code -

```
txtPhoneWork.Text.Replace("-","");
        txtPhoneWork.Text.Replace("_", "");
        txtMobile.Text.Replace("-", "");
        txtMobile.Text.Replace("_", "");
        txtPhoneOther.Text.Replace("-", "");
        txtPhoneOther.Text.Replace("_", "");

        location.ContactWork = txtPhoneWork.Text.Trim();
        location.ContactMobile = txtMobile.Text.Trim();
        location.ContactOther = txtPhoneOther.Text.Trim();
```

but it is not replacing and is there any method so that both `-` and `_` can be replaced in single function.

Comment: As characters are different you should define seperate functions to your code. If same character replacement means you can have a single function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) *returns* the string with the replacement performed (it doesn't change the original string, they're immutable), so you need a format like this:

```
txtPhoneWork.Text = txtPhoneWork.Text.Replace("-","");
```

Comment: there would be a space in "", Replace("-"," "); OR Replace("-","");

Answer (score 0):

get the replaced string in some variable

you can try this to replace multiple characters in single function
string value= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.replace(value, @"[-_]", "");