# Replace spaces in string, mvc razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am very new to MVC and razor, but I am enjoying it so far.  There are one or two basics I am having trouble with so hopefully this will be a nice easy one for someone.

I am making a new variable and replacing the white spaces. However, this doesn't appear to be working at all; the space that I am adding to the string myself remains.  I cannot simply use the underscore at this point as both `Address1` and `Postcode` may also contain spaces, so the replace is essential.

```
@{ 
    var mapAddress = Model.Address1 + ", " + Model.Postcode;
    mapAddress.Replace(" ", "_");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace special character from string in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726267/how-to-replace-special-character-from-string-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must use the return value of pure method `Replace`, that is:

```
mapAddress = mapAddress.Replace(" ", "_");
```

Comment: I'm actually ashamed to have failed so hard!  Sometimes the most obvious things pass me by.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd say most people have made this mistake at some stage.  Sometimes a unit test of even the most simple bits of code helps you understand and remember what the code better.